# Vimscript: Number of listed buffers

Tags: vim, viml

In my vimscript, I need to get a count of all buffers that are considered listed/listable (i.e. all buffers that do *not* have the unlisted, 'u', attribute).

What's the recommended way of deriving this value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `bufnr()` to get the number of the last buffer, then create a
list from 1 to that number and filter it removing the unlisted buffers, by
using the `buflisted()` function as the test expression.

```
" All 'possible' buffers that may exist
let b_all = range(1, bufnr('$'))

" Unlisted ones
let b_unl = filter(b_all, 'buflisted(v:val)')

" Number of unlisted ones
let b_num = len(b_unl)

" Or... All at once
let b_num = len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)'))
```

Comment: I'm under the impression that this answer don't quite address the OP's question. He asked for "listed", not "unlisted". Although I see how it is related, of course. But I believe the answer would be simpler, and I'm curious to how that would be. -- Edited: it seems it do answer by filtering the unlisted "out"

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution is using [`getbufinfo`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getbufinfo%28%29).

In your vimscript:

```
len(getbufinfo({'buflisted':1}))
```

or test it with command:

```
:echo len(getbufinfo({'buflisted':1}))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it by calling `buflisted()` on the range of numbers up to the largest buffer number given by `bufnr("$")`. Something like this:

```
function! CountListedBuffers()
    let num_bufs = 0
    let idx = 1
    while idx <= bufnr("$")
        if buflisted(idx)
            let num_bufs += 1
        endif
        let idx += 1
    endwhile
    return num_bufs
endfunction
```